# ng-repeat with multiple filters on large data set

Tags: angularjs

I'm still new to AngularJS, so I'm just trying to do a simple CRUD app. Currently I pull the data (in a JSON file) with `$http` in a `div` handled by a controller `MyCtrl1`.

```
function MyCtrl1($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/accounts.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.accounts = data;
    ...
    }); 
}
```

Inside this `div` is a `table` with the following `tbody`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="account in accounts | orderBy:sort.field:sort.desc | startFrom:currentPage * pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
        <td contentEditable="true" ng-repeat="(label, value) in account" ng-show="fields[label].visible">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The `orderBy` filter sorts according to a selected field; `startFrom` slices the array to start at a certain point; `limitTo` filters according to a preset page size. Without the pagination filters the performance was pretty terrible, but I was wonder if there was an alternative way to go about this?

I have Batarang for Chrome and under the Performance tab it showed `ngRepeatWatch` taking up  the most time, and I reckon it has to do with all the filtering I'm doing..

Answer (score 73):

[{{ expression | filter1 | filter2 }}](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Just use

```
<tr ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter1 | filter2 | filter3" >
  <td contentEditable="true" ng-repeat="(label, value) in account" ng-show="fields[label].visible">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

[Angular 2](https://angular.io/) uses [pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html), but its looks like filters:

```
<div>The chained hero's birthday is
<p>{{  birthday | date:'fullDate' | uppercase}}</p>
<div>
```

Comment: that is filter1 AND filter2 AND filter3.  Possible to do filter1 OR filter2 OR filter 3

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is old but for anyone in the future.  Filtering in line is expensive (computationally) because it works directly on the DOM, if you are dealing with large amounts of data, 1000+ rows, it is much better to filter your collection in your controller then repeat on that instead.

Answer (score 4):

I'd handle pagination in the controller or server-side.  My guess is that ng-repeat is watching your *entire* list instead of just what it needs to watch, which is going to be very slow.

Comment: So `ng-repeat` is actually making instances of _every_ record in the dataset, and the filters only hide those instances, rather than not constructing them?

Comment: Frankly, that's a guess.  Is Batarang listing all of the rows in the Model or just the ones you've filtered?

Comment: It's only showing models for my filtered accounts, which seems right. The only other thing I can think of is that each account has 43 fields that are `ng-repeat`ed. These are toggled show/hide, so they're still in the DOM and have models.

Comment: You might be getting bitten by this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651578/how-to-unwatch-an-expression

Comment: I'll consider writing a directive in the future, but I saw a 4x speed-up in ngRepeatWatch after filtering the hidden columns instead of `ng-show`ing them. Silly me

Answer (score 0):

This is not a filter but you can use a ng-hide directive evaluating the $index for the array as following:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12" ng-repeat="message in messages | orderBy: '-id' as filtered_result track by message.id  ">
  <div class="card-box widget-user" ng-hide="{{$index >= 4}}">
    <div>
      <img ng-src="{{message.imageUrl}}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{message.imageUrl}}">
      <div class="wid-u-info">
        <h3 class="m-t-0 m-b-5">{{message.title }}</h3>
        <p class="text-muted m-b-5 font-13" ng-bind-html="message.content | ellipsis:147 | trusted"></p>
        <!-- <p class="text-muted m-b-5 font-13">{{message.content | limitTo:130}}</p> -->
        <small class="label" ng-class="{'label-success':message.type=='Message','label-warning':message.type=='Announcement'}"><b>{{message.type}}</b></small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CRUD should be handled in a factory or service, not in the controller. My understanding is that a controller is only responsible for communication between the views and services.

Edit 1: excerpt from John Papa Style Guide (Angular -1) - Defer logic in a controller by delegating to services and factories.

Why?: Logic may be reused by multiple controllers when placed within a service and exposed via a function.

Why?: Logic in a service can more easily be isolated in a unit test, while the calling logic in the controller can be easily mocked.

Why?: Removes dependencies and hides implementation details from the controller.

Why?: Keeps the controller slim, trim, and focused.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y035