# ng-repeat: how to add multiple filters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'd like to use multiple filters on the same item for an ng-repeat. The idea is that for each job below I have different properties like location and salary and I'd like to be able to filter the results with both criteria.

So far, I've tried this:

```
<div ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter: location | filter: salary">
```

But it's obviously not working.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I guess it should work, checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126905/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-multiple-filters-on-large-data-set) post

Comment: By default the filter would do something similar to AND. So filter where `location` value and `salary`  value are there. Else you should look at custom filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom filter.

```
<div ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:customFilter">
```

And in your controller :

```
 $scope.customFilter = function(item) {
   if('Condition on your item')
     return true;
   return false;

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use parenthesis to nest expressions:

```
<div ng-repeat="(job in job | filter:location) | filter:salary">
```