# can we still apply filter from ui on the filteredlist based on the tab which is active in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the below two tabs and the ng-repeat which displays the data in the table.

```
<div class="details-table">
<ul class="table-toggle">
   <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'personal'}"><a href="#" ng-click="setActiveTab('personal')" class="">Personal</a></li>
   <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'professional'}"><a href="#" ng-click="setActiveTab('professional')" class="" >Professional</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="scrollable-table-box">
    <table>
          //rest of the code here.......
         <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | filter:item.usertype = (activeTab == 'Personal' ? 'Personal': 'Professional')">
         // rest of the code here........
    </table>
 </div>
```

when user clicks on the personal tab the pagedItems which is already a filtered list should be further filtered by item.usertype == "personal" and similarly when clicked on professional tab it should be further filtered by item.usertype == "professional". The reason I want to do it this way is original collection pagedItems (which is filtered using search input earlier) will always be the same and only based on the tab the data is filtered to show in the ui.

I tried implementing this by adding another level of filter in the ng_click() of each tab. But this way either I need to maintain an additional variable or overwrite the same variable which for me doesn't look like an elegant solution.

Is it possible to do the same from html using ng directive filter?

Comment: Just use {{ expression | filter1 | filter2 }} in your case <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | filter1 | filter2 | filter3" >. This already discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126905/ng-repeat-with-multiple-filters-on-large-data-set

Comment: Will the pagination be adjusted accordingly by the further filters we applied using filter : ?

Comment: so you can instead use functions to calculate filters rather than using `$filter` but one thing you may want to take into account is linking urls, when people want to share a paginated, filtered list with someone else, how are you going to maintain that information.