# Angular JS filter 2 values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have a filter:

```
angular.module('pb.ds.foundation').filter('notAvailable', function () {
  return function (items, name) {
    var arrayToReturn = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i].code !== name) {
        arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
      }
    }

    return arrayToReturn;
  };
});
```

which I wrote to filter out a given item from an ng-repeat:

`ng-repeat="nio in icons.nucleoIcons | notAvailable: 'arrows-2_time'"`

Now, however, I'd like to filter a *second* icon (string) from my repeater.  Do I need to pipe the same filter a second time with the new value, or is there a way to pass the filter 1 *or more* values?

Comment: You can use multiple filters in the ng-repeat. See this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126905/ng-repeat-with-multiple-filters-on-large-data-set

Comment: I know I can (and have) used multiple filters, but never with the _same_ filter twice.

Comment: It seems to work, but is that the "correct" way?

Comment: That's a good question Steve.You got me looking around for it and it doesn't appear that it's something frowned upon. Technically you could do the logic in your filter, inside the ng-repeat filter, so I suppose nothing is stopping you. All you've done is move the logic out into a filter, so keep it separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways you can accomplish this. You can pass a string to the filter, as you did, but you can also pass an array or a scope variable as well.

Here is a [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2qvfDgMJeyCgpyDIXclA?p=preview) that has the filter updated to accept a string, array, or scope variable.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('notAvailable', function () {
  return function (items, name) {
    var arrayToReturn = [];

    if (Array.isArray(name)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (name.indexOf(items[i].code) === -1) {
          arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].code !== name) {
          arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    return arrayToReturn;
  };
})
```