# How to not update a model until form submission in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, binding

**I'm looking for Angular to not update the model until the user submits the form**. Or, in another way, to update the model **only** when the user has submitted the form.

```html
<form ng-submit="process()">
    Value is : {{ model.property }}
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.property">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I was thinking of something like `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: null }"` but it doesn't work.

Is this even possible without it getting too "hacky" (like getting each input's value on submit)?

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240168/genuinely-stop-a-element-from-binding-unbind-an-element-angularjs

Comment: Have a shadow model. OnSubmit copy the form model to the real model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should clone your object using `angular.copy`.

```
 $scope.formData = angular.copy($scope.model);

<form ng-submit="process()">
    Value is : {{ formData.property }}
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.property">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then on process you update the model.

```
 $scope.model = angular.copy($scope.formData);
```

You will be using a temporary model instead of your "real" one.