# In AngularJs, how do you bind and unbind data-ng-mousemove from the controller?

Tags: angularjs

I've bound mousemove of my app to check if the user is still using it:

```
<body data-ng-mousemove="data.OnMouseMove()"
```

where my controller does this:

```
$scope.data.OnMouseMove = function ()
{
    AccountService.RefreshToken();
};
```

This works fine but breaks animations if the user continuously moves the mouse.  So I want to disable the mousemove event for 20 seconds but don't know how to. Something like this pseudocode:

```
$scope.data.OnMouseMove = function ()
{
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].data-ng-mousemove = "";

    AccountService.RefreshToken();

    window.setTimeout(function () 
    {
       document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].data-ng-mousemove = "data.OnMouseMove()";
    }, 20000);
};
```

Comment: Have you considered putting ```AccountService.RefreshToken();``` inside the "setTimeout" callback body?

Comment: Alternatively, you might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240168/genuinely-stop-a-element-from-binding-unbind-an-element-angularjs

Comment: Maybe you want to [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) your mouse move handler?

Comment: Thanks all, yes, my refresh token method is throttled and takes almost 0 milliseconds. But just having the mousemove event on the body causes this event to trigger constantly. I need to actually completely unbind and later rebind the event, not just do less in it. Checking out Sphaso's link now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any way of dynamically changing the ng-mousemove event.  AngularJS is just not designed that way.

The only other AngularJS option might be to write a custom attribute directive and dynamically use $compile and $destroy to change it.  But I don't know enough to do that.

The simplest and fastest solution is simply to use a non-Angular Javascript event that you can easily bind and unbind, and in that event call the Angular service.

Like so:

```
"use strict";

var HandleMouseMoveOnBody = function()
{
    var htmlScope = angular.element(document.getElementById('htmlId')).scope(); //get access to angular from the outside
    htmlScope.data.OnMouseMove(); //refresh the token in Angular service

    $('body').off('mousemove'); //stop watching mouse movement as it slows the entire page

    //watch mouse movement again in a minute
    window.setTimeout(function() 
    {
        $('body').on('mousemove',  HandleMouseMoveOnBody);
    },  55000);        
};

//start watching
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('body').on('mousemove', HandleMouseMoveOnBody);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a flag in your service if the token has been recently refreshed. If that's the case then just return void in your mouse over event.