# Unbind ng-change AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

Hi I want to know is there is a way to stop a ng-change function from been executed programatically.

I am building a search suggestions feature that calls an API using `ng-change` (passing the input, send it to a `service`, then back to the `controller` with the model created). But If the user decides, she/he can click a button to disable the feature. As far as I know, I can make stop the API calls, but not the event itself from being fired.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: Take a look at to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240168/genuinely-stop-a-element-from-binding-unbind-an-element-angularjs

Comment: This worked!... thanks!

Comment: This link provided by Turdaliev did the trick for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240168/genuinely-stop-a-element-from-binding-unbind-an-element-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

I think that's exactly you are looking for:

```
<input ng-change="userDecision || doSomething()">
```

Comment: What else you need? I solved your problem. User decision is a bool variables, if use wants can disable doSomethind() setting userDecision variable to false.