# How to disable ng-model dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `ng-model` in an `input` tag, such as

```html
<input ng-model="someModel" type="file" />
```

At some point in the execution I'm interested in disabling/removing the `ng-model` so that the `input` won't be affected anymore by changes to `someModel`.

I've tried to select the input element and then apply `element.removeAttr("ng-model")` but the element still seems to be reacting to changes to `someModel`.

My guess is that this is happening due to the digest cycle. So how do I disable/remove the ng-model?

Comment: you can use a custom validator that you force to false, then your input will result invalid and will not update your model

Comment: Here is another solution (which seems a bit convoluted to me): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240168/genuinely-stop-a-element-from-binding-unbind-an-element-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

Have two inputs with ng-if condition. ng-if can remove element from DOM.

```
<input ng-model="someModel" type="file" ng-if="condition1" />
<input ng-model="" type="file" ng-if="!condition1" />
```

Comment: Thank you. This can help as a workaround to achieve what I need. But it actually doesn't answer the question of how to really remove/disable the ng-model. I don't want to have 2 inputs, and remove one of them conditionally, but rather have only 1 input whose ng-model is removed. In my case the input is generated inside a directive, so it complicates things...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of one way to do this is by using a controller. It basically binds the input to a dummy variable and calls an ng-change function.  In the controller you can place your logic on whether or not you want the input to update someModel.  In the example, a checkbox determines whether or not to update.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.update = true;
    $scope.dummyChanged = function(dummy) {
      if ($scope.update) {
        $scope.someModel = dummy;
      }
    }

  }
])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="controller">
    Type value in here
    <input ng-model="dummy" ng-change="dummyChanged(dummy)" />
    <br />Click here to allow updates to model
    <input ng-model="update" type="checkbox" />

    <pre>
        someModel: {{someModel}}
        update: {{update}}
      </pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```