# Unbinding $watch in angularjs after called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frameworks

I know you can unbind a $watch like this:

```
var listener = $scope.$watch("tag", function () {});
// ...
listener(); // would clear the watch
```

but can you unbind the watch within the watch function declaration. So after the watch gets executed once, it unbinds itself? Something like:

```
$scope.$watch("tag", function () {
    unbindme()
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13652152/333777 should be relevant

Answer (score 60, accepted):

you can just do it the same way you already do, call the "deregistration" inside your function:

```
var unbind = $scope.$watch("tag", function () {
    // ...
    unbind();
});
```

Comment: `listener` would be better named `unbind`.

Comment: @daniellmb anything wrong if I call `listener()` once more ? I have a piece of code where the `listener()` is executed only if a condition is satisfied. So is ther any problem if I call the unbinding function again, outside ( maybe inside `scope.$on('destroy')` ), just to make sure ?

Comment: @Dane you can call it as many times as you wish, easy to test too

Answer (score 10):

Because `tag` is an expression, you can use [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) to unbind once the value was received:

```
$scope.$watch("::tag", function () {});
```

```js
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('example', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.tag = undefined
  $scope.$watch('::tag', function(tag) {
    $scope.tagAsSeen = tag
  })
  $interval(function() {
    $scope.tag = angular.isDefined($scope.tag) ? $scope.tag + 1 : 1
  }, 1000)
})
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'])
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="example">
Tag: {{tag}}
<br>
Watch once result: {{tagAsSeen}}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

bindonce directive maybe what you need.

https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

Answer (score 0):

```
var unbindMe=$scope.$watch('tag',function(newValue){
    if(newValue){
       unbindMe()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39991175/2518317), a slight improvement to @Kris' answer will get you something more sleek and re-usable throughout the project.

```js
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.see = function(v, func) {
        var unbind = this.$watch(v, function() {
            unbind();
            func.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    };
})
```

Now thanks to scope prototypical inheritance you can simply go

```js
$scope.see('tag', function() {
    //your code
});
```

And not worry about unbinding at all.