# Unsubscribing to a closed variable inside its own callback

Tags: javascript

I only want to listen to something once. Is this valid javascript?

```
  const unsubscribe = obj.onFoo(x => {
    unsubscribe()
    // do things
  })
```

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? This is my first time working with an API that returns an unsubscribe function, and it looks a bit strange to me. It works, but I'm unsure about the implications it may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly valid way of calling `unsubscribe()`.

Even though the function is not assigned to the `unsubscribe` variable until after the function is constructed, it is not *run* until the callback is called. When the callback is called, it looks for the `unsubscribe` identifier and finds it in the *enclosing scope*. The identifier resolves to the unsubscribe function, and so `unsubscribe()` is called as you would expect.

This is a fairly common pattern. Just one example off the top of my head is clearing a `$watch` function in AngularJS – [Unbinding $watch in angularjs after called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394204/unbinding-watch-in-angularjs-after-called)