# angularjs ng-repeat and ng-model does not go well with textarea/input tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I generate input tags with ng-repeat and assign ng-model within custom directive
it invokes directive on every key stroke.

This is Demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/Oku8EH?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = ["1234567"];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($compile, $timeout) {
  var num=0;
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      console.log('this happens with every keyup event in textarea when ng-model is given as arr[$index], why?');
    }
  };
});


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  arr[0] : {{arr[0]}} <br/>
  <input my-directive ng-repeat="str in arr" ng-model="arr[$index]" />
  </input>
</body>
```

It's strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `ng-repeat` is reevaluating each time you change the `arr` Array as it must be watching it (see line l256 [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/2e9d7cc6cb9665fa00d7796b2a51fb9a2c41af1a/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L256%20%27%27here) in ngRepeat sources on Github)

If you point the model on another array, everything is OK.

You can check it out with this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDj5MY9NVV6XHeGMrdBa).

Comment: Also may want to check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651578/how-to-unwatch-an-expression Which explains how To have a repeater with a large array that you don't want to watch every item.

Comment: I tried `str in arr track by $index`, message is not happening. How does it different?