# Rendering conditional markup with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, markup, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Given this data in my controller :**

```
$scope.data = [
    {id: "1", ElementType: "paragraph", text: "some content"},
    {id: "2", ElementType: "listItem", text: "some list item content"},
    {id: "3", ElementType: "quote", text: "some quote"}
]
```

**An given this ng-repeat in my view:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.text}}</div>
```

**How can I render this HTML ? :**

```
<p>Some content</p>
<ul>
    <li>some list item content</li>
</ul>
<blockquote>some quote</blockquote>
```

I've explored ng-switch but it keeps the parent div. In other words I want to replace the HTML produced by ng-repeat with new markup based on an object attribute.

Comment: Try `ng-if` inside the `ng-repeat` directive?

Comment: Thanks Tony. I Tried ng-if. Like ng-switch it works but only for the markup inside the `<div ng-repeat="item in data" ...`. I need to get rid of the wrapper div.

Comment: You cannot get rid of the `<div ng-repeat...>` element. Otherwise you won't be looping over anything. If you want to remove the parent post-render you could always use javascript to do DOM manipulation, but I don't understand why you'd want to do that.

Comment: I have to deal with a database with aweird structure that specifies the type of HTML element each content is supposed to use. I'd like to render the cleanest markup possible. Some HTML elements specified by the data are inline elements such as `<span>`, so getting rid of the div is important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it inside a directive using the `$compile` angular function like shown in [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/orxmDS?p=preview) plnkr.

**UPDATE**
[Here is a plnkr that works better](http://plnkr.co/edit/TUkSbc?p=preview)

Here is the key part:

```
link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
  scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {

    var htmlStr = '';
    var repeat = attrs.repeat;
    for(var i = 0; i< repeat; i++){
      htmlStr += html;
    }

    ele.html(htmlStr);
    $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
  });
}
```

Your controller would look like this:

```
function MyController($scope) {

$scope.html = '<p>{{id}}</p>\
              <ul>\
               <li>{{ElementType}}</li>\
              </ul>\
             <blockquote>{{text}}</blockquote>';
}
```

From your example, you'd remove the ng-repeat entirely and just use this directive. One change is that you'd pass in the whole $scope.data and dynamically pull out the bits you wanted to use in your html string. But because it's a string, that should be easy to do with simple string concatenation.

One final thing - you are probably going to have to put some tags in so you can replace your static content with dynamic data from your array. Kind of like ng-repeat! (but different all the same).

Finally, you could use `interpolate` to fill up your html string:

```
$interpolate(template)({
  id: id,
  ElementType: ElementType,
  text: text
});
```

Where you would get the data for these items from the controller

Comment: Have you had any luck using this technique?

Comment: Wow ! Looks like a great direction. Thanks ! Let me try to figure out exactly how to implement this (I'm learning Angularjs). Thanks a lot.

Comment: CaspNZ, I can't see your addition in the plnkr. All i CAN see is the first code.

Comment: Try this - it's all working for me in this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/TUkSbc?p=preview (I've updated the answer plnkr to)

Comment: With your solution in mind I did some more searching on similar custom ng-repeat solution and found this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651578/how-to-unwatch-an-expression), a very simple and elequent way to refactor ng-repeat for performance boost. Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJnLD3eS5wyyN7qq9UP9?p=preview) illustrating what I came up with based on this strategy

Answer (score 1):

just nest `ng-if` in `<div ng-repeat=...>`.

For `else` you can use `ng-if` with reversed condition

Comment: Interesting Koner. But I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "reversed condition". Can you please elaborate ? Can I get rid of the parent div that contains the ng-repeat directive ?

Comment: ng-if="isType == true" and reversed condition ng-if="isType == false"

Comment: I mean the same what @dasu908 wrote