# Is a variable enclosed in {{ }} checked for changes on my page?

Tags: angularjs

I thought there was a way that I can just display something on the page and not have AngularJS check it for changes.

Can someone tell me how to do this?  Is it just if I have a label like this:

{{ abc }}

Comment: Please include the full code and a better description.  If `abc` be a scoped variable, then yes Angular will update it.

Comment: I want it to display data from scope but it's just display only.  {{ abc }} will display it.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I want to display a grid full of data and want to do many lines so I know if I use ng-model it's going to watch all the inputs.  How can I make it so it doesn't watch or update what's displayed if the model changes.

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with maintaining a set of scoped variables which are snapshots of the model values?  This way, when the model changes these values would not also change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use binding like this `{{::abc}}` so you app will not watch for changes after first render of the data. See [one-time-binding doc](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/expression#one-time-binding)

Answer (score 0):

It is a scope variable. Means your controller has an scope object as $scope if you define any variable like `$scope.abc = "string"`. then a new property called `abc` will be created in your controller scope.
In AngularJS scope object was always watched and once any change in that object made it will reflect in the view.

Comment: But is there a way I can do it so it's not watched? I just want to create a report with a 1000+ rows.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651578/how-to-unwatch-an-expression

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, Angular 1.3 and up versions has put a lot of effort into performance with the feature [One-time binding](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/expression#one-time-binding) using {{ ::abc }} works:

```js
angular
    .module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.abc = 'Some text'

        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.abc = 'new value';
            console.log('Changed but not reflected in the view:', $scope.abc);
        }, 1000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <p>{{ ::abc }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is a two-way data binding, angular will watch for any changes on the variable $scope.abc and update the DOM with the changes. However if you want to make sure it does not watch for any changes you can go for the one-way binding, where any change made to the variable will not be watched upon by angular. You can do this using by `{{::abc}}` or `ng-bind="::abc"`.

For example refer - https://jsfiddle.net/m8L2pogg/